# Realm Swift EXC_BAD_ACCESS when creating RealmSwift Object

Tags: ios, swift, realm

### UPDATE:  I updated the correction of my definition of Realm, I still get the error.

I'm using Swift and RealmSwift to build my small App and I'm having multiple errors while trying to make it work. The errors I get are mainly from trying to read Objects from the database, since writing them seems to work sometimes. I asked a question previously which was answered with a way to set up the Realm Objects, but now I get this EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. Lets begin with my RealmManager class in which I create the Realm Instance.

```
import RealmSwift
import Foundation

class RealmManager {
  private var configured: Bool

  private var init(){
    self.configured = false
  }

  static let shared = RealmManager()

  lazy var realm: Realm = {
    if !self.configured {
      var config = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration
      let realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)
    } else {
      let realm = try! Realm()
    }
    return realm
  }

  func configure() throws {
    let dbName = "MyApp.realm"
    var dbConf = Realm.Configuration()

    guard let url = dbConf.fileURL?.deletingLastPathComponent().appendingLastPathComponent(dbName) else {
      throw DBError.databaseNameError
    }
    dbConf.fileURL = url
    dbConf.readOnly = false
    dbConf.schemaVersion = 1
    do {
      self.realm = try Realm(configuration: dbConf)
      self.configured = true
    } catch {
      throw DBError.configurationError
    }
  }
```

Then I call the class from my AppDelegate class:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate {
  var window: UIWindow
  var realmM: Realm!
  var pushToken: String = ""

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions : [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?)-> Bool {
    self.realmM = openRealm()
    return true
  }

  private func openRealm() -> Realm {
    do {
      try RealmManager.shared.configure()
    } catch {
      print("Didnt configure Realm")
    }
    let realm = RealmManager.shared.realm
    return realm
  }
}
```

Now this is how I declare 3 of my objects in which I get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Carga: Object{
  @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var idCarga : Int32
  @Persisted var idPedido : Int32
  @Persisted var units : Int32
  @Persisted var packages : Int32
  @Persisted var kilograms : Double

  convenience init(_id: Int32, idPedido: Int32, uds: Int32, pkgs: Int32, kgs: Double) {
    self.init()
    self.idCarga = _id
    self.idPedido = idPedido
    self.units = uds
    self.packages = pkgs
    self.kilograms = kgs
  }
}

class Pedido : Object{
  @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var idPedido : Int32
  @Persisted var idLugar : Int32
  @Persisted var cargas = RealmSwift.List<Carga>()  --> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1,adress=0x0)

  convenience init(_id: Int32, idLugar: Int32, listCargas: RealmSwift.List<Carga>) {
    self.init()
    self.idPedido = _id
    self.idLugar = idLugar
    self.cargas = listCargas
  }
}

class Lugar : Object{
  @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var idLugar : Int32
  @Persisted var name : String
  @Persisted var pedidos = RealmSwift.List<Pedido>()  --> Thread 1 :EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1,adress=0x0)

  convenience init(_id: Int32, name: String, listPedidos: RealmSwift.List<Pedido>) {
    self.init()
    self.idLugar = _id
    self.name = name
    self.pedidos = listPedidos
  }
}
```

- IDs are defined as Int32 because the value is read from Firebase Int32 format.
- The error *Thread1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x0)* is thrown in the following lines:

1- From RealmManager

> self.realm = try Realm(configuration: dbConf)

2- From Realm class

> Realm.init()

3- RLMObjectSchema PropertiesForClass

> getProperties(_:)

4- From the Object initialization

> Pedido.init()

> Carga.init()

5- From the Object properties

> @Persisted var cargas = RealmSwift.List()

> @Persisted var pedidos = RealmSwift.List()

*Do not compile this code block. It is just a representation of the pathing that the Thread1 is following when creating the Realm instance and where the error is happening.*

Comment: There's a typo in the Pedido class `self.cargas = listaCargas` which should be `listCargas`. I copy and pasted your three classes into a project and they all worked correctly. That would mean the issue lies in how Realm is being called or initialized. This is not a valid Realm config `let configration = DBConfig(` and we don't know what that is specifically but all of that code could be replaced with about 8 lines so why not simplify it? It will make troubleshooting and maintaining much easier. Also, why are `objectTypes` being defined?

Comment: Oh, and for a design pattern, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65960304/how-to-access-a-realm-database-from-multiple-controllers-swift/65981914#65981914)

Comment: I dont know, I am following every answer you give me. Realm is confgured as you did in multiple answers and you also seem to have tested the code and it worked. So, why is my App throwing a Thread EXC_BAD_ACCESS when reading a RealmSwift.list with the persisted definition if it is the right way to do it? I am using Realm 10.42.1.

Comment: I never get an error on console its just the EXC_BAD_ACCESS that can't let my App to run

Comment: I see there's an update to the code in your question; however, I cannot get it to compile. There are a number of syntax error's in the code and it's incomplete. As a test, visit the answer linked above, comment out all of your Realm code and replace it with the code in the question from the RealmService singleton solution. Use it exactly as written - copy and paste. Then add the code to create and write one of each of your objects. Do not create relationships or anything else. Just keep it simple like this `let c = Carga()` and then get realm and write the object. Report back your findings.

Comment: @Jay I just updated the question again. I believe everything is properly written with no syntax errors, you should be able to compile it since i am able to. Maybe try to omit the DBError calls since its an independent custom class. Please try to give me a more specific answer about what I am asking. I am using the singleton declaration of Realm just like you say in the linked answer. You say keep it simple but it is important to add the database name, path and readonly property. I could just do the default config but I belive it wouldnt work as intended. Anyways the error's in the RealmObjects

Comment: There are still errors when copy and pasting the code so I have no idea how it's compiling for you. For example, this is invalid 'private var init(){' as it's missing the var name OR it should just be an init, and there *must* be a space between () and { - *Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'*. Then this doesn't have a proper initializer `lazy var realm: Realm = {` won't compile - *Function produces expected type 'Realm'; did you mean to call it with '()'?*. Part of the issue duplicating the problem is the errors in the code. Can those be addressed?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error lies in how Realm is configured and the timing of when it's called (AppDelegate?), not the objects themselves.

It seems that you're attempting to create a realm var that persists throughout the app and that's generally not best practice. Realm is not thread safe and objects and app function could run on different threads; that would cause the types of errors you're seeing.

Best practice is to instantiate a Realm object when needed, or per the below example via a singleton pattern. Rule of thumb is it's better to create instances of Realm on demand rather than pre-emptively creating an instance ahead of time and retaining it

> When calling Realm(configuration:), Realm itself will internally cache
> that object and will return the same object on each subsequent call.
> The object remains in the cache until the autoreleasepool it was
> created in is drained.
> -- from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43775459/realm-in-multithreaded-environments)

I will use the code for the three objects (copy and pasted) from the question (see bottom of this answer)

Then, i'll adopt some code from [an answer to a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65960304/how-to-access-a-realm-database-from-multiple-controllers-swift/65981914#65981914) and modify it to write the Realm file to my Mac desktop (iOS functions are similar). You can point the URL to wherever fits your use case. This `RealmService` is a singleton that should be placed outside of any other classes.

```
class RealmService {
    private init() {}

    static let shared = RealmService()

    lazy var realm: Realm = {
        //modify below to be your iOS URL/path
        let manager = FileManager()
        let homeURL = manager.homeDirectoryForCurrentUser
        let desktopURL = homeURL.appendingPathComponent("Desktop")
        let pathToThisRealmFile = desktopURL.appendingPathComponent("desktopRealm.realm")
        //modify above to be your iOS URL/path

        var config = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration
        config.fileURL = pathToThisRealmFile
        let realm = try! Realm.init(configuration: config)
        return realm
    }()
}
```

Note that I am not calling any code from my AppDelegate as there's no reason to. The RealmService only needs to be referenced when you're interacting with Realm. Note this code is for local realm; a Sync'd realm can/should be handled differently.

Then the code to instantiate and write three objects; a Carga, Pedido and Lugar. I added a button to my UI that when clicked, creates the three objects in my desktop Realm.

```
func handleButtonClick() {
    let a = Pedido()
    let b = Lugar()
    let c = Carga()

    let realm = RealmService.shared.realm
    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(a)
        realm.add(b)
        realm.add(c)
    }
}
```

This this code is run and the button is clicked, three files appear on my desktop; desktopRealm.realm, desktopRealm.realm.lock, desktopRealm.realm.management (which is a folder).

Upon inspection, the desktopRealm.realm file contains the three objects as expected.

---

Realm Objects from question

```
class Carga: Object{
  @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var idCarga : Int32
  @Persisted var idPedido : Int32
  @Persisted var units : Int32
  @Persisted var packages : Int32
  @Persisted var kilograms : Double

  convenience init(_id: Int32, idPedido: Int32, uds: Int32, pkgs: Int32, kgs: Double) {
    self.init()
    self.idCarga = _id
    self.idPedido = idPedido
    self.units = uds
    self.packages = pkgs
    self.kilograms = kgs
  }
}

class Pedido : Object{
  @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var idPedido : Int32
  @Persisted var idLugar : Int32
  @Persisted var cargas = RealmSwift.List<Carga>()

  convenience init(_id: Int32, idLugar: Int32, listCargas: RealmSwift.List<Carga>) {
    self.init()
    self.idPedido = _id
    self.idLugar = idLugar
    self.cargas = listCargas
  }
}

class Lugar : Object{
  @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var idLugar : Int32
  @Persisted var name : String
  @Persisted var pedidos = RealmSwift.List<Pedido>()

  convenience init(_id: Int32, name: String, listPedidos: RealmSwift.List<Pedido>) {
    self.init()
    self.idLugar = _id
    self.name = name
    self.pedidos = listPedidos
  }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry I tried both ways, my realm configuration and your realm configuration both stop my code in the same line. I figure this must be an issue with storing other Realm objects inside one Realm object. This database is not working for me and I am replicating the error, showing my code and there's no active support from Realm developers. I could use more help from other devs. You have been very helpful @Jay I understand how Realm works now but we both are unable to solve this Threading error apparently.

Comment: @DMarMon You must have some other issue involved and there is no threading in the answer in my code so it would not be possible to have a threading error. The code I posted in my answer is straight from a fully working project, which I use on three different Macs. Possibly corrupted data, bad OS, malware or something else unrelated to the code. Why don't you create a brand new project, add Realm SDK and then copy and paste my code. Should only take about 10 minutes and that will establish a baseline as if it doesn't work, you have other issues causing the problem.

Comment: I wanted to express my sincere gratitude for all the help you provided me. Your support was truly valuable, and I deeply appreciate the time and effort you put into trying to assist me.
However, after giving it a try and exploring different options, I've decided to opt for SQLite3 as it proved to be much easier for me to understand.
Although I'm discarding Realm this time, I will consider it again in the future. Your advice and guidance will be of great value if I decide to revisit Realm.
Thank you again for your kindness and willingness to help. I hope you have a fantastic day!